# data.table reshape with alternating columns

Tags: r, data.table, reshape

I have a data frame with alternating columns that I want to reshape. The problem is that `stats::reshape` and `reshape2::reshape` are both very slow and memory intensive on my actual use case. I suspect that the no-copy approach of `data.table` will save me time and use less resources, but I barely know where to start with the syntax (previous related efforts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16494665/1036500), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16494665/1036500)).

Here's an example of how my data frame is structured:

```
set.seed(4)
dt <- data.frame(names = letters[1:10],
       one = rep(23,10), 
       two = sample(1000,10),
       three = sample(10,10),
       onea = rep(24,10), 
       twoa = sample(1000,10),
       threea = sample(10,10),
       oneb = rep(25,10), 
       twob = sample(1000,10),
       threeb = sample(10,10),
       onec = rep(26,10), 
       twoc = sample(1000,10),
       threec = sample(10,10), 
       oned = rep(26,10), 
       twod = sample(1000,10),
       threed = sample(10,10))
```

Which looks like this:

```
   names one two three onea twoa threea oneb twob threeb onec twoc threec oned
1      a  23 586     8   24  715      6   25  939      4   26  561      4   26
2      b  23   9     3   24  996      3   25  242      7   26   72      6   26
3      c  23 294     1   24  506      8   25  565      8   26  852     10   26
4      d  23 277     7   24  489      5   25  181      6   26  911      3   26
5      e  23 811     9   24  647      9   25  901      5   26  225      5   26
6      f  23 260     6   24  827      7   25   84      3   26  626      8   26
7      g  23 721     4   24  480      2   25  896      1   26   69      2   26
8      h  23 900     2   24  836      4   25  886     10   26  512      9   26
9      i  23 942     5   24  510      1   25  718      2   26  799      1   26
10     j  23  73    10   24  526     10   25  560      9   26  964      7   26
   twod threed
1   911      2
2   709     10
3   571      5
4   915      9
5   899      3
6    59      1
7    46      4
8   982      7
9   205      8
10  921      6
```

Here's what I'm currently doing with `stats::reshape` which takes a long time and uses a lot of memory on my actual use case:

```
df_l <- stats::reshape(dt, idvar='names',
                   varying=list(ones = colnames(dt[seq(from=2, 
                                to=ncol(dt), by=3)]), 
                                twos = colnames(dt[seq(from=4, 
                                to=ncol(dt), by=3)])), 
                   direction="long")
```

Here's the desired output (I don't care about any of the `three` columns):

```
 df_l
    names two twoa twob twoc twod time one three
a.1     a 586  715  939  561  911    1  23     8
b.1     b   9  996  242   72  709    1  23     3
c.1     c 294  506  565  852  571    1  23     1
d.1     d 277  489  181  911  915    1  23     7
e.1     e 811  647  901  225  899    1  23     9
f.1     f 260  827   84  626   59    1  23     6
g.1     g 721  480  896   69   46    1  23     4
h.1     h 900  836  886  512  982    1  23     2
i.1     i 942  510  718  799  205    1  23     5
j.1     j  73  526  560  964  921    1  23    10
a.2     a 586  715  939  561  911    2  24     6
b.2     b   9  996  242   72  709    2  24     3
c.2     c 294  506  565  852  571    2  24     8
d.2     d 277  489  181  911  915    2  24     5
e.2     e 811  647  901  225  899    2  24     9
f.2     f 260  827   84  626   59    2  24     7
g.2     g 721  480  896   69   46    2  24     2
h.2     h 900  836  886  512  982    2  24     4
i.2     i 942  510  718  799  205    2  24     1
j.2     j  73  526  560  964  921    2  24    10
a.3     a 586  715  939  561  911    3  25     4
b.3     b   9  996  242   72  709    3  25     7
c.3     c 294  506  565  852  571    3  25     8
d.3     d 277  489  181  911  915    3  25     6
e.3     e 811  647  901  225  899    3  25     5
f.3     f 260  827   84  626   59    3  25     3
g.3     g 721  480  896   69   46    3  25     1
h.3     h 900  836  886  512  982    3  25    10
i.3     i 942  510  718  799  205    3  25     2
j.3     j  73  526  560  964  921    3  25     9
a.4     a 586  715  939  561  911    4  26     4
b.4     b   9  996  242   72  709    4  26     6
c.4     c 294  506  565  852  571    4  26    10
d.4     d 277  489  181  911  915    4  26     3
e.4     e 811  647  901  225  899    4  26     5
f.4     f 260  827   84  626   59    4  26     8
g.4     g 721  480  896   69   46    4  26     2
h.4     h 900  836  886  512  982    4  26     9
i.4     i 942  510  718  799  205    4  26     1
j.4     j  73  526  560  964  921    4  26     7
a.5     a 586  715  939  561  911    5  26     2
b.5     b   9  996  242   72  709    5  26    10
c.5     c 294  506  565  852  571    5  26     5
d.5     d 277  489  181  911  915    5  26     9
e.5     e 811  647  901  225  899    5  26     3
f.5     f 260  827   84  626   59    5  26     1
g.5     g 721  480  896   69   46    5  26     4
h.5     h 900  836  886  512  982    5  26     7
i.5     i 942  510  718  799  205    5  26     8
j.5     j  73  526  560  964  921    5  26     6
```

How can I do this with `data.table`?

Comment: There's no such thing as `reshape2::reshape` - do you mean `reshape2::melt`?

Comment: Yes, you're right, thanks. Is a `dreshape2` in the works (or `reshape3` or whatever)? I mean a `reshape2` with the amazing C++ speed of `dplyr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this very specific case I think following approach might be faster.

You create a list of data.tables with specific columns that you need to combine vertically (i.e. `one`s and `two`s). That is accomplished by `lapply(seq(3,15,3), function(j) { DT[, c(1, j-1,j+1), with=F ]})`

and you use `rbindlist` which is a faster version of `rbind` which joins `data.tables` or `data.frames` together without checking the column orders etc. (which is what makes it fast).

Finally you merge the resultant data.table `DT2` back with part of original data.table `DT` which you want repeated. i.e `DT1` which has only columns `names, two, twoa, twob, twoc, twod` from the original data.table

```
DT <- data.table(dt)

DT1 <- DT[, list(names, two, twoa, twob, twoc, twod)]

DT2 <- rbindlist(lapply(seq(3,15,3), function(j) { DT[, c(1, j-1,j+1), with=F ]}))

setkey(DT1, names)
setkey(DT2, names)

RES <- DT1[DT2]

RES
##     names two twoa twob twoc twod one three
##  1:     a 586  715  939  561  911  23     8
##  2:     a 586  715  939  561  911  24     6
##  3:     a 586  715  939  561  911  25     4
##  4:     a 586  715  939  561  911  26     4
##  5:     a 586  715  939  561  911  26     2
##  6:     b   9  996  242   72  709  23     3
##  7:     b   9  996  242   72  709  24     3
##  8:     b   9  996  242   72  709  25     7
##  9:     b   9  996  242   72  709  26     6
## 10:     b   9  996  242   72  709  26    10
## 11:     c 294  506  565  852  571  23     1
## 12:     c 294  506  565  852  571  24     8
## 13:     c 294  506  565  852  571  25     8
## 14:     c 294  506  565  852  571  26    10
## 15:     c 294  506  565  852  571  26     5
## 16:     d 277  489  181  911  915  23     7
## 17:     d 277  489  181  911  915  24     5
## 18:     d 277  489  181  911  915  25     6
## 19:     d 277  489  181  911  915  26     3
## 20:     d 277  489  181  911  915  26     9
## 21:     e 811  647  901  225  899  23     9
## 22:     e 811  647  901  225  899  24     9
## 23:     e 811  647  901  225  899  25     5
## 24:     e 811  647  901  225  899  26     5
## 25:     e 811  647  901  225  899  26     3
## 26:     f 260  827   84  626   59  23     6
## 27:     f 260  827   84  626   59  24     7
## 28:     f 260  827   84  626   59  25     3
## 29:     f 260  827   84  626   59  26     8
## 30:     f 260  827   84  626   59  26     1
## 31:     g 721  480  896   69   46  23     4
## 32:     g 721  480  896   69   46  24     2
## 33:     g 721  480  896   69   46  25     1
## 34:     g 721  480  896   69   46  26     2
## 35:     g 721  480  896   69   46  26     4
## 36:     h 900  836  886  512  982  23     2
## 37:     h 900  836  886  512  982  24     4
## 38:     h 900  836  886  512  982  25    10
## 39:     h 900  836  886  512  982  26     9
## 40:     h 900  836  886  512  982  26     7
## 41:     i 942  510  718  799  205  23     5
## 42:     i 942  510  718  799  205  24     1
## 43:     i 942  510  718  799  205  25     2
## 44:     i 942  510  718  799  205  26     1
## 45:     i 942  510  718  799  205  26     8
## 46:     j  73  526  560  964  921  23    10
## 47:     j  73  526  560  964  921  24    10
## 48:     j  73  526  560  964  921  25     9
## 49:     j  73  526  560  964  921  26     7
## 50:     j  73  526  560  964  921  26     6
##     names two twoa twob twoc twod one three
```

Another way is to just use `data.table:::melt.data.table` function twice (once for `ones` and another time for `threes` and `cbind` the results together

```
RES <- cbind(data.table:::melt.data.table(DT, id.vars=c(1,seq(3,15,3)), 
       measure.vars = seq(2,14,3), value.name='one', variable.name="onevar")[,-7, with=F], 
       data.table:::melt.data.table(DT, id.vars=c(1), measure.vars = seq(4,16,3),
       value.name='three', variable.name="threevar")[, 3, with=F])

RES
##     names two twoa twob twoc twod one three
##  1:     a 586  715  939  561  911  23     8
##  2:     a 586  715  939  561  911  24     6
##  3:     a 586  715  939  561  911  25     4
##  4:     a 586  715  939  561  911  26     4
##  5:     a 586  715  939  561  911  26     2
##  6:     b   9  996  242   72  709  23     3
##  7:     b   9  996  242   72  709  24     3
##  8:     b   9  996  242   72  709  25     7
##  9:     b   9  996  242   72  709  26     6
## 10:     b   9  996  242   72  709  26    10
## 11:     c 294  506  565  852  571  23     1
## 12:     c 294  506  565  852  571  24     8
## 13:     c 294  506  565  852  571  25     8
## 14:     c 294  506  565  852  571  26    10
## 15:     c 294  506  565  852  571  26     5
## 16:     d 277  489  181  911  915  23     7
## 17:     d 277  489  181  911  915  24     5
## 18:     d 277  489  181  911  915  25     6
## 19:     d 277  489  181  911  915  26     3
## 20:     d 277  489  181  911  915  26     9
## 21:     e 811  647  901  225  899  23     9
## 22:     e 811  647  901  225  899  24     9
## 23:     e 811  647  901  225  899  25     5
## 24:     e 811  647  901  225  899  26     5
## 25:     e 811  647  901  225  899  26     3
## 26:     f 260  827   84  626   59  23     6
## 27:     f 260  827   84  626   59  24     7
## 28:     f 260  827   84  626   59  25     3
## 29:     f 260  827   84  626   59  26     8
## 30:     f 260  827   84  626   59  26     1
## 31:     g 721  480  896   69   46  23     4
## 32:     g 721  480  896   69   46  24     2
## 33:     g 721  480  896   69   46  25     1
## 34:     g 721  480  896   69   46  26     2
## 35:     g 721  480  896   69   46  26     4
## 36:     h 900  836  886  512  982  23     2
## 37:     h 900  836  886  512  982  24     4
## 38:     h 900  836  886  512  982  25    10
## 39:     h 900  836  886  512  982  26     9
## 40:     h 900  836  886  512  982  26     7
## 41:     i 942  510  718  799  205  23     5
## 42:     i 942  510  718  799  205  24     1
## 43:     i 942  510  718  799  205  25     2
## 44:     i 942  510  718  799  205  26     1
## 45:     i 942  510  718  799  205  26     8
## 46:     j  73  526  560  964  921  23    10
## 47:     j  73  526  560  964  921  24    10
## 48:     j  73  526  560  964  921  25     9
## 49:     j  73  526  560  964  921  26     7
## 50:     j  73  526  560  964  921  26     6
##     names two twoa twob twoc twod one three
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much. Your first solution is easily adaptable to my actual use case (adding `RES[order(one)]` etc.) and has cut the time from 15.52 sec to 0.47 sec, a nice 15x increase in speed.

Answer (score 2):

Since version 1.8.11, data.table supports `melt` in reshape2. and also `dcast.data.table`. You can check manual for more examples and details.

This problem can be solved by selecting based on substring match.

```
require(reshape2)
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(dt)
dt_melt <- melt(dt, id = c(1,3,6,9,12,15))
a <- dt_melt[like(variable,"one"), ]
b <- dt_melt[like(variable,"three"), value]
c <- a[, three:= b][, time := ceiling(.I/10)][, variable := NULL]
setnames(c, "value", "one")
```

The logic here is quiet simple, first melt, and then select based on substring match.

I don't know whether you real data have such pattern such as `one`, and `three`. Maybe there need some modifications if not.

Here's the result.

```
     names two twoa twob twoc twod variable   one three time
 1:     a 586  715  939  561  911      one    23     8    1
 2:     b   9  996  242   72  709      one    23     3    1
 3:     c 294  506  565  852  571      one    23     1    1
 4:     d 277  489  181  911  915      one    23     7    1
 5:     e 811  647  901  225  899      one    23     9    1
 6:     f 260  827   84  626   59      one    23     6    1
 7:     g 721  480  896   69   46      one    23     4    1
 8:     h 900  836  886  512  982      one    23     2    1
 9:     i 942  510  718  799  205      one    23     5    1
10:     j  73  526  560  964  921      one    23    10    1
11:     a 586  715  939  561  911     onea    24     6    2
12:     b   9  996  242   72  709     onea    24     3    2
13:     c 294  506  565  852  571     onea    24     8    2
14:     d 277  489  181  911  915     onea    24     5    2
15:     e 811  647  901  225  899     onea    24     9    2
16:     f 260  827   84  626   59     onea    24     7    2
17:     g 721  480  896   69   46     onea    24     2    2
18:     h 900  836  886  512  982     onea    24     4    2
19:     i 942  510  718  799  205     onea    24     1    2
20:     j  73  526  560  964  921     onea    24    10    2
21:     a 586  715  939  561  911     oneb    25     4    3
22:     b   9  996  242   72  709     oneb    25     7    3
23:     c 294  506  565  852  571     oneb    25     8    3
24:     d 277  489  181  911  915     oneb    25     6    3
25:     e 811  647  901  225  899     oneb    25     5    3
26:     f 260  827   84  626   59     oneb    25     3    3
27:     g 721  480  896   69   46     oneb    25     1    3
28:     h 900  836  886  512  982     oneb    25    10    3
29:     i 942  510  718  799  205     oneb    25     2    3
30:     j  73  526  560  964  921     oneb    25     9    3
31:     a 586  715  939  561  911     onec    26     4    4
32:     b   9  996  242   72  709     onec    26     6    4
33:     c 294  506  565  852  571     onec    26    10    4
34:     d 277  489  181  911  915     onec    26     3    4
35:     e 811  647  901  225  899     onec    26     5    4
36:     f 260  827   84  626   59     onec    26     8    4
37:     g 721  480  896   69   46     onec    26     2    4
38:     h 900  836  886  512  982     onec    26     9    4
39:     i 942  510  718  799  205     onec    26     1    4
40:     j  73  526  560  964  921     onec    26     7    4
41:     a 586  715  939  561  911     oned    26     2    5
42:     b   9  996  242   72  709     oned    26    10    5
43:     c 294  506  565  852  571     oned    26     5    5
44:     d 277  489  181  911  915     oned    26     9    5
45:     e 811  647  901  225  899     oned    26     3    5
46:     f 260  827   84  626   59     oned    26     1    5
47:     g 721  480  896   69   46     oned    26     4    5
48:     h 900  836  886  512  982     oned    26     7    5
49:     i 942  510  718  799  205     oned    26     8    5
50:     j  73  526  560  964  921     oned    26     6    5
    names two twoa twob twoc twod variable value three time
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, I'm getting `Error in is.factor(vector) : object 'variable' not found` for your lines that creates `a`, `b` and `c`. Any thoughts?

Comment: oh，you need to convert your data.frame into data.table first.